# Opening HiSuite daemon on Huawei phone

Tags: wine, phone

I am trying to communicate my android Huawei Y330 to 'HiSuite' that runs under 'Wine'. Someone had suggested to first connect the Huawei Y330 to 'HiSuite' run under 'Windows'. Thus the 'HiSuite daemon', as he called it, would be installed on the phone.

I quote:

"First I installed wine. Then I downloaded HiSuite (Huawei's official PC suite) Link to download page and installed it.

Then I had to connect my phone to a windows PC, so the HiSuite daemon was installed on the phone.

When that is done, just open the HiSuite daemon on the phone and choose connect with wiFi. Enter the code on HiSuite on the PC, and voila. Now the phone is connected to ubuntu :)"

I have done this and could not find any 'HiSuite daemon' on my phone to open.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Installing this drivers solve it for me

https://github.com/siddht4/Huwaei_linux_drivers

Comment: This is not an answer.. It would be better if you comment rather than posting answer..

Comment: seems like an answer to me, but maybe you could add the installation instructions to it